# Add a mysql record from php

Tags: php, mysql

Why does this code not work?
I need to insert a new record on mysql called "utenti" but this code doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $nome = $_REQUEST["nomeUtente"];
    $cognome = $_REQUEST["cognome"];
    $psw = $_REQUEST["psw"];
    $email = $_REQUEST["email"];
    $cell = $_REQUEST["num"];           

    echo $nome . " / " . $cognome . " / " . $psw . " / " . $email . " / " . $cell;
    echo "<br>";

    $conn = mysql_connect("hostName","User","password");

    if(!$conn){
        echo "connessione non satabilita";
    }else{
        if(!mysql_select_db("a4102239_utenti",$conn)){
            echo "database non trovato";
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (id,psw,nome,cognome,email,cellulare) VALUES (NULL,'$psw','$nome','$cognome','$email','$cell')"; //costruzione comando di ricerca      
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You must run your query, of course! mysql_query($sql, $conn);

Answer (score 1):

Execute the query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO utenti (id,psw,nome,cognome,email,cellulare) VALUES (NULL,'$psw','$nome','$cognome','$email','$cell')"); //costruzione comando di ricerca
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not Execute the Query,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO utenti (id,psw,nome,cognome,email,cellulare) VALUES (NULL,'$psw','$nome','$cognome','$email','$cell')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
// Query is executed
}
else{
//Error
echo mysql_error();
}
```